# tests failing when "Run All Test in Solution" is used

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4, mvccontrib-testhelper

I am trying to get unit tests to run successfully for my MVC 4 Web Application project.

When I run the tests classes individually all of the tests pass, when I come to run all test in solution only 2/9 pass, I have clicked Debug Checked Tests and they all pass when I the hit run again they also all pass.

This problem is also being replicated when I check the project into TFS, I have setup continuous integration they project builds, runs the tests and fails on exactly the same tests.

The error I'm getting back is ***"A route named '' is already in the route collection"**

Does anybody have any ideas why this might be happening?

In each class I have a [TestInitialize] block which is shown below:

```
[TestInitialize]
public void Setup()
{
    var builder = new TestControllerBuilder();
    controller = new MyController();
    builder.InitializeController(controller);

    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

I had a similar error in the classes when I hadn't included the TestControllerBuilder, could it be that this code is not running correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`RouteTable.Routes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routetable.routes.aspx) is static and therefore will only be initialized once per AppDomain.

So every time you run a test, you are in effect trying to re-register the same routes over again.

You would probably be better off moving your route registration into an [`AssemblyInitialize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assemblyinitializeattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute so it will only run once at the beginning of the entire test run.

Comment: what would be the best course of action to get routeconfig to only run once for all the tests I am trying to test a large number of routes, would it be best to have a single test intialize class which runs for all the test classes?

Comment: am using MvcContrib TestHelper to check whether a specific route maps to it's corresponding controller (9 in total)